# how do you make ubuntu directory shortcuts for the desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I right click the desktop and do "create launcher" and then set the type to "location" and then browse to a file inside the folder, select it (with the inappropriately named "open" button) and then manually edit the path to remove the file name, leaving only the path to the folder.  I'm on Ubuntu 10.10.

If there are no files in the folder, create one before doing "create launcher", and then after you have the shortcut, clean-up by deleting the file.  This is such a nice process.

How can I make folder shortcuts without manually editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Nautilus by either typing `nautilus` in the terminal, or by picking one of the Places in Gnome system menu, **drag** the desired folder from Nautilus to place you want (Desktop, for example) **using the middle mouse button**. As a result, you will have the popup-menu, where you can select one of the options:

- Move Here
- Copy Here
- Link Here
- Cancel

`Link Here` is the option you actually want.

Comment: If you consider "move" to be in a sense a semi-destructive operation, and I do, it's perhaps too easy to pick "move", which is the first choice in a middle button drag.  It might be a little less risky to right click in Nautilus and then "make link" and then drag the link to the desktop.

Comment: Since you are using Linux, there is numerous options to do the same operation (`ln -s /tmp ~/Desktop/temp`). I've proposed the easiest way how I would do it, IMHO.